# Illustrator cc divide tool not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have created a simple ellipse and then from one end to the other created a path using the pen tool that intersects this ellipse. I now want to divide the ellipse into two shapes using the path, however no matter what I do I can't get this to work.

I am trying to use the pathfinder - divide tool, but when I apply this effect nothing happens, I have tried grouping the objects but still nothing works. Is there a simple trick that I need to apply to get this to work?

[The ellipse I am trying to divide in two and the path I want the division to be made along](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLlO7.png)

Comment: Guessing... use the **Pathfinder Panel** not the *menu command*.

Comment: Hi @Scott how do I access that panel? Thank you

Comment: `Window > Pathfinder` or Command/Ctrl-Shift-F9

Comment: Worked perfectly! If you write up an answer quickly I can accept it. I dont know why that would make a difference but thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to realize that the menu item `Effect > Pathfinder` is **not** the same as using the **Pathfinder Panel** (`Window > Pathfinder`).

The menu item strives to keep all artwork "live" and editable. So, while operations are completed, not all operations will result in a change to the actual artwork. The menu applies an **Effect** to the existing artwork. it does not change the artwork though. If you are seeking to *actually* alter the artwork, you should choose to use the buttons on the Pathfinder Panel, rather than the menu items. (Note; you could also use the menu item but then you need to be certain to choose `Object > Expand` to "bake in" the pathfinder effect if needed).

Random extra: Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key while clicking a button on the Pathfinder Panel will make the buttons work the same way the Pathfinder Menu items work.